# Heroku CLI not killing the postgres connections

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

Postgres db provisioned at Heroku runs out of DB connections very frequently which hinders debugging the application on local system.

While try killing the connection via Heroku CLI, nothing happens. It pops "Not Found" message. It seems the command is not able to locate the db within the heroku app.

[image]

Need some help on killing postgre DB connections, so as to debug the application.

I tried executing

```
heroku pg:info -a heroku-sizing-roi-dev
```

It returns [image]

But the database is provisioned already with DB schema and tables created. I can browse the DB on heroku dashboard and connect it via Java application.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.